# Can't Build a PC StandAlone Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: My first error]

I'm new to Unity 3D Game Development and I've learned the very first game Roll a Ball by watching tutorials but in the end stuck in a problem that I am not able to Build my Project from the Build Settings PC Standalone Module, Error occurs:

> `No PC/MAC standalone Module loaded.`

I don't understand where would be the problem, I have also attached the screenshot of my question.

Comment: Here is not a good place to look for a tutorial.  Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: This question should be closed I think because it's not related to programming. Just read info from your own screenshot: "No PC, Mac & Linux Standalone module loaded" and button "Open download page". Its pretty obvious what you have to do.

Comment: I Clicked the Button but it reloaded me to Unity - Not Found Website....

Comment: Thank you brother for teaching how to ask questions ... :)

Answer (score 2):

As Droppy mentioned, it looks as though you are missing the Windows Build Support module.

However, you don't have to reinstall Unity, you can just run the [Download Assistant](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstallingUnity.html) and just select the Windows Build Module from there. That will install the module, without reinstalling Unity.

[image]

Close and reopen Unity, and it should work fine.

Comment: @KaranHemnani if any of the answers to your question have solved your problem, don't forget to mark them as correct! :-)

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstallingUnity.html), you can decide what modules to install when you install Unity.  It looks like you didn't install the *Windows Build Support* module.

To rectify, I would recommend re-installing Unity (it's probably been patched since, anyway).